# Error while editing product from backend

Tags: magento2

I don't know why this is happening. when i click edit/add product button i got error

> Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class
>   Mageplaza\Productslider\Model\Slider\Source\FeaturedProducts does not
>   exist

I have downloaded Product slider but it is not working properly so i remove it today. 
I have upgrade my magento 2 setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension you added most probably added a product attribute.
Look in the `eav_attribute` table for records

```
WHERE `source_model` LIKE '%Mageplaza%' OR 
      `backend_model` LIKE '%Mageplaza%' OR 
      `frontend_model` LIKE '%Mageplaza%'
```

and delete the rows you find.

Backup the db before just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Marius. After removing entry from this table everything is fine

Answer (score 2):

**This Solution was helpful.** 
I also uninstalled the "Mageplaza\Productslider" extension and my product detail page stopped working in M2

Search for records in `eav_attribute` table and delete it

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` 
WHERE `source_model` LIKE '%Mageplaza%' 
OR `backend_model` LIKE '%Mageplaza%' 
OR `frontend_model` LIKE '%Mageplaza%'
```